# Jasper report - big text field in a confined space

Tags: jasper-reports

One of my text fields is very long(eg :4000 characters). I want the data to be displayed in my fixed width/height column. The data could be truncated for the display . But when i click the column in my excel jasper report, I would want to be able to see and copy the entire data . Is there a way to do this in jasper? The stretch with overflow, displays the entire text field value and changes the column height which I do not want.

The display truncation is fine. But I would want to be able to copy the entire data . Any help would be much appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured out there is a property:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
```